# How do I solve an equation with three terms, with the unknown inside a square root, inside a third root, in two of them?

Tags: arithmetic

The equation is $$\\ \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{a}+b}+\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{a}+b}=k.$$

How do I find$\ a$?

Comment: Had a chance to look at my answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Uh, sorry, though it is true that yesterday I wasn't home, I checked my notifications but no sign of your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$k=(b+c)^{1/3}+(b-c)^{1/3}$$ where $c=\sqrt a$. We use $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$.

$$k^3=b+c+b-c+3(b^2-c^2)^{1/3}k=2b+3k(b^2-c^2)^{1/3}$$

Now subtract $2b$, divide by $3k$, cube, subtract from $b^2$, and you have $c^2$, which is $a$.

Answer (score 1):

There are some nice cancellations.  It will look less imposing if we let $c=\sqrt a$  Then we have $$\sqrt[3]{c+b}+\sqrt[3]{-c+b}=k\\
(c+b)+(b-c)+3\sqrt[3]{2b(b^2-c^2)}=k^3\\3\sqrt[3]{2b(b^2-c^2)}=k^3-2b$$ an you are on your way.

Comment: How do you get$\ 3\sqrt[3]{2b\left(b^2-c^2\right)}$ from$\ 3\sqrt[3]{\left(b+c\right)^2(b-c)}+3\sqrt[3]{\left(b-c\right)^2(b+c)}$?